# How to check with Json or Curl when a page looks empty?

Tags: php

I have a function that loops some data with JSON.

The problem is that weh nmy foreach loop finds this situation here `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=berlusca&limit=10&type=post&until=1327422514` it stops working...

How can I check when the page has empty data??

This is my foreach:

```
function getPostInfo($url, $lang, $stopwords) {
$j = json_decode(startCurl($url));
foreach($j->data as $v) {
if ($v->type == 'status') {
        $post['author_id'][] = $v->from->id;
        $post['original_id'][] = $v->id;
        $ret['post_url'][] = getPostUrl($original_id, $author_id);
        //$description = stopWords($v->message);
        $post['description'][] = $v->message;
        $post['pub_date'][] = $v->created_time;
    }
}   
 return $post;
}
```

Comment: What does it mean stops working? And you're not initializing `$post`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count($j->data) > 0 ) {
  foreach ...
}
```